# Get values from each table rows

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use this code to validate table with single row:

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div/div"));
        for (WebElement e : tableRows) {
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("projectLookupCodes")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("loadContainerSequence")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("67", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("packagedItemCount")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("23", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("locationName")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("Location", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("licensePlateLookupCode")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("LP-12160", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("shipmentLookupCode")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("520031", e.getText());
            }
        }
```

HTML code:

https://pastebin.com/TCRVLvpf

How I can verify each table row? Currently it's searching for first row and so on. How this code can be extended to search for several table rows values.

Comment: How many rows does this represent `driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div/div"))` ?

Comment: I think only one.

Comment: Is the data you assert is fixed? every row will always have the text?

Comment: Into the HTML snippet see for example line 40: value for `LP-520154</div>` into every line it's different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you are very close to the solution.
All what you need is to retrieve all the rows from the table and for each row find all it's cells.
Now you can iterate over each cell in the internal loop and validate its` value.

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']//div[@role='row']"));
    for(WebElement row :tableRows){
        List<WebElement> rowCells = row.findElements(By.xpath(".//div"));
        for (WebElement e : rowCells) {
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("projectLookupCodes")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("loadContainerSequence")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("67", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("packagedItemCount")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("23", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("locationName")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("Location", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("licensePlateLookupCode")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("LP-12160", e.getText());
            }
            if (e.getAttribute("col-id").equalsIgnoreCase("shipmentLookupCode")){
                System.out.println("AssertEquals value " + e.getText());
                assertEquals("520031", e.getText());
            }
        
    }
```

Comment: But I see one problem here: it will work if the table word data is all the same into every row. How I can use assert if I have different data?

Comment: Well, you didn't provide any information about this... What data can be there? Can you provide more details? As I see in the HTML code you provided all the rows have same list of  `col-id` attributes

Comment: In case you want me to try adding more / different validations please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//div[@class='ag-center-cols-container']/div"));
        String projectLookupCodes = ".//div[@col-id='projectLookupCodes']";
        String loadContainerSequence = ".//div[@col-id='loadContainerSequence']";
        String packagedItemCount = ".//div[@col-id='packagedItemCount']";
        String locationName = ".//div[@col-id='locationName']";
        String licensePlateLookupCode = ".//div[@col-id='licensePlateLookupCode']";
        String shipmentLookupCode = ".//div[@col-id='shipmentLookupCode']";
        
        for(WebElement e: tableRows) {
            if(e.findElement(By.xpath(projectLookupCodes)).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("ProjectLookupCodes: "+e.findElement(By.xpath(projectLookupCodes)).getText());
            }
            if(e.findElement(By.xpath(loadContainerSequence)).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("loadContainerSequence: "+e.findElement(By.xpath(loadContainerSequence)).getText());
            }
            if(e.findElement(By.xpath(packagedItemCount)).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("packagedItemCount: "+e.findElement(By.xpath(packagedItemCount)).getText());
            }
            if(e.findElement(By.xpath(locationName)).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("locationName: "+e.findElement(By.xpath(locationName)).getText());
            }
            if(e.findElement(By.xpath(licensePlateLookupCode)).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("licensePlateLookupCode: "+e.findElement(By.xpath(licensePlateLookupCode)).getText());
            }
            if(e.findElement(By.xpath(shipmentLookupCode)).isDisplayed()) {
                System.out.println("shipmentLookupCode: "+e.findElement(By.xpath(shipmentLookupCode)).getText());
            }
            System.out.println("=============================");
        }
```

Comment: This code doesn't validate anything, just prints the content.

Comment: @Guy : yeah that just need  `assertEquals()` - but that should not be a concern. It's a logic that may need tweak. Let OP comment first.

Comment: How I can use assert if I have different data?